# Origen y uso de "manque"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, conjunciones

Por aquí por mi tierra hay una frase popular, un grito de guerra casi, que dice así:

> ¡Viva el Betis *manque* pierda!

Siempre me ha llamado la atención ese *manque*, incorporado a la expresión hasta tal punto que a nadie se le pasa por la cabeza decir *aunque*, manque todo el mundo sabe que significa eso.

Esta palabra no está registrada a día de hoy en el diccionario, pero se pueden encontrar registros en algunos diccionarios anteriores, como los *Academia manual* de 1927 y 1950, donde se define así:

> Vulgarismo por **aunque**.

En la versión de 1927 se añade además que era de uso en Salamanca y Murcia. Me llama la atención esto, por la distancia entre las dos ciudades, y porque veo que se usa en más sitios además de en Sevilla. Esta información también se puede encontrar en alguna que otra ficha del *Fichero general* de la RAE. De hecho, una ficha de 1977 recoge dos posibles etimologías:

> Cuervo, en *Disquisiciones filológicas*, apunta que dicha forma puede ser el resultado de un antiguo cruce entre *[maguer](https://dle.rae.es/maguer)* y *aunque*, mientras Rosemblat sostiene que representa un cruce entre *aunque* y *[masque](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=masque)*, expresión concesiva esta última que es usada en la literatura antigua a partir del *Conde Lucanor* con el sentido de *aunque*. La forma *manque* subsiste en diversas regiones de España y América.

Veo también en el CORDE que algunos autores ya usaban *manque* en sus obras en el siglo XIX, como Benito Pérez Galdós y Ángel Ganivet en España y Tomás Carrasquilla en Colombia. Así que al final la palabra sí que se usa en los dos lados del charco.

Dado que me gustaría profundizar algo más en el origen de esta curiosa palabra, pregunto:

- ¿Desde cuándo se usa la expresión? ¿Qué registros son los más antiguos de entre los que usan esta palabra con este significado?
- ¿Cuál es la etimología más plausible?
- ¿En qué lugares se usa o conoce la palabra? De momento, tenemos Sevilla, Murcia, Salamanca y algunos países de América como Colombia. ¿Se conoce en más sitios?

Comment: Desde cuándo se usa la expresión? | ¿Cuál es la etimología más plausible? | ¿En qué lugares se usa o conoce la palabra? => No hay aquí tres preguntas distintas (aunque evidentemente relacionadas)? Para la tercera (dónde se usa o entiende) solemos hacer respuestas tipo wiki.

Comment: @Diego las respuestas de tipo wiki son para los casos de preguntas tipo "cómo se dice esto en cada país hispanoblante", pero aquí no pido eso porque el término es fijo. Este tipo de preguntas se suele responder con una consulta al DAMER para ver los países donde se usa la voz, solo que _manque_ no aparece en el DAMER. Por lo demás, yo prefiero unir en una pregunta las dudas relacionadas con un mismo vocablo, pero si consideráis que hay que separar, yo me ciño a lo que decidáis.

Comment: Charlie, no te quito la razón, pero por otro lado luego tienes respuestas que pueden ser solo "En mi país X sí/no se usa/entiende" (sin añadir más ni atender a las dos primeras consultas hechas en la pregunta). Y estas contribuciones quedan en una zona gris (para algunos son demasiado _low quality_, para otros son _técnicamente_ validas aunque no tengan mucho mérito, para otros son tan válidas como una respuesta que responda a las tres consultas realizadas). Por otro lado "manque" es lo suficientemente particular para no merecer 3 preguntas en lugar de 1. Hazlo como quieras. Faltaría menos.

Answer (score 2):

[**Sobre el origen y distribución de manque (aunque)**](http://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/fichero_articulo?codigo=3824417&orden=0):

> Esta breve nota gramatical resume los posibles orígenes de la conjunción rural *manque* (*mas aunque, mas que, anque y mal que*) y su distribución en español peninsular (gracias a los datos del Atlas Lingüístico de la Península Ibérica, ALPI) y americano, además de ofrecer abundante documentación de todas esas formas.
>
> ...
>
> 5. En resumen, los ejemplos presentados anteriormente de las formas *mas
>    aunque, mas que, anque* y *mal que* nos ayudarían a comprender mejor el camino que ha
>    seguido la forma asimilada manque, conservada en español rural desde antiguo. Como ya
>    indicaron varios autores antes que nosotros, su origen y evolución debe haber sido la
>    siguiente: *aunque> anque> manque*, con prótesis nasal<sup>52</sup> , o bien ser el fruto del cambio consonántico *mas que > manque* (-s- > -n-) o *mal que> manque* (-l- > -n-)<sup>53</sup>. Parece más probable, por tanto, suponer la presencia de mas aun que, secuencia documentada desde la Edad Media, que sincopada dio lugar a *manque*. En cualquier caso, nunca ha sido considerada una forma correcta, ni ha pasado a la lengua culta, precisamente por esta alteración fónica vulgar, quedándose como “característica de la lengua rústica y de algunas variedades de la popular”<sup>54</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor explicación que he escuchado sobre el origen de "manque" ha sido de boca del catedrático de Lengua y Literatura Española, Javier Pérez Orozco. El video no es nada pesado, todo lo contrario:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3bDd-4a4cw

Extracto del video (la explicación propiamente dicha comienza aquí, en 5:09):

> El Arcipreste de Hita, Don Juan Ruiz, ése en El libro del buen amor
> emplea ya una palabra que está considerada una joya de la literatura y
> la lengua española: es un arcaísmo. Manque es el resultado de la unión
> de dos consonantes: *maguer* y *anque*. *Maguer*, ya desapareció de la
> lengua, y *anque*, no ha desaparecido todavía porque todavía se usa en
> algunos sitios como en Andalucía, que es especialista en conservar
> arcaismos, que mucha gente ignorante  confunde con vulgarismos porque
> ya no los oye.